# What good are badges? New feature suggestion

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I understand badges represent "feats" on SO, but I think they can also be a great tool to reward individuals who show dedication to making the community better. With rep, you earn a certain amount, and you get extra privs like editing or voting, etc..

I propose that within questions that qualify for your badge, you get extra votes. For instance,for every silver C++ badge, you now get the chance to "extra upvote" questions and answers tagged C++. When you get a gold C++ badge, your upvotes don't count towards the poster's daily 200 rep limit.

To clarify, these benefits would be limited to only within the area which you earned the badge.

Comment: Edited to be more constructive

Answer (score 5):

Badges are a slightly different dimension than rep.

They measure participation in ways that a reputation score number cannot.

You can have a very high reputation without ever getting a gold badge, for example. Just browse around the user profiles and you'll see what I mean.

And good luck getting the tag-based badges, which are elusive indeed:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags

Comment: I understand they *are* a different dimension, but other than a nifty color on the screen they just summarize what is already present in your answer history. They *signify* notable achievements, but don't *reward* notable achievements. My suggestions helps elucidate the meaning of being highly respected by earning a gold or silver badge. Your opinion/experience now carries more weight in the community (rightly so I believe).

Comment: the idea that one person's vote should "count more" than another person's vote is undemocratic -- not something we will ever support.

Comment: Jeff, 
Clearly you are saying that your vote counts more, because it (the feature) is something you will never support. That isn't democracy, that's a dictatorship. (Your site, you have the right I'm just saying). In a representative democracy, we elect those who we believe should wield power and make decisions for us. I *want* people who are great at C++ to be able to highlight great questions and answers with more authority than someone who has not been proven to be all that great.

Comment: Ironically I don't see a lot of community votes for this feature, so I'd say the democracy is working at the moment :)

Comment: If that's so, it's fine with me. I just hope you let the question stand and let people decide. I don't have any problem with being wrong or having a bad idea, it just means I need to think of something different, or be satisfied with the way things are. I love SO and it is tremendously useful. Thank you for all the great work to make it so thus far.